# nodejs pgpromise - help using massive transaction

Tags: node.js, pg-promise, exceljs

I'm using pgpromise on a nodejs app.  One of the things I'm doing is upserting many records, more than 10000 records.  The original way I was doing this is via using db.tx, and returning a batch.  The only issue with this approach is that one it takes awhile, and two it loads a massive amount of promises into an array and consumes a bunch of memory.

Here is what I currently do...

```
var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
return db.tx(function (t) {
                    var insertStatements = [];
                    var upsertProcessedData = this.getSql('./sql/upsertProcessedData.sql');
                    for (var i = 2; i <= worksheet._rows.length; i++) {
                        // need to convert strings to dates for postgres insert
                        // console.log('Working row ' + i);
                        worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(8).value = new Date(worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(8).value);

                        // here we create a new array from the worksheet, as we need a 0 index based array.
                        // the worksheet values actually begins at element 1.  We will splice to dump the undefined element at index 0.
                        // This will allow the batch promises to work correctly... otherwise everything will be offset by 1
                        var arrValues = Array.from(worksheet.getRow(i).values);
                        arrValues.splice(0, 1);

                        // these queries are upsert.  Inserts will occur first, however if they error on the constraint, an update will occur instead.
                        insertStatements.push(this.one(upsertProcessedData, arrValues));
                    }
                    console.log('Begin inserts');
                    return t.batch(insertStatements);
                }).then( blah blah blah...)
```

This approach works, it's just really slow once I get a large worksheet of data.

I stumbled upon using `sequence` but am struggling to understand how it works.  Per the documentation, it states to use it like so..

```
function source(index, data, delay) {
    // must create and return a promise object dynamically, 
    // based on the index of the sequence; 
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return this.query('select 0');
        case 1:
            return this.query('select 1');
        case 2:
            return this.query('select 2');
    }
    // returning or resolving with undefined ends the sequence; 
    // throwing an error will result in a reject; 
}

db.tx(function (t) {
    // `t` and `this` here are the same; 
    return this.sequence(source);
})
```

What I don't understand is how to allow my "source" function access to the data in my worksheet?  Where does the "data" parameter come from in the source function?  Seems I can't just pass my worksheet obj into my source function.
Rather, I would like to try the sequence approach, but I'm unsure of how to access my queryfile containing the sql, as well as how to iterate over my worksheet with this sequence function...

Edit:
So after reading what Vitaly wrote about the sequence, as well as looking at the github issue, here is what I came up with:

```
Promise.bind(promiseBindObject)
    .then(function (workbook) {
        return this.workbook.xlsx.readFile(this.fileName);
    }).then(function (workbook) {
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
        // console.log(worksheet.name);
        var upsertProcessedRqData = db.getSql('./sql/upsertProcessedRqData.sql');
        function source(index, data, delay) {   
            // create and return a promise object dynamically,
            // based on the index passed;
            var arrValues = worksheet.getRow(index).values;
            if (index < worksheet._rows.length) {
                return this.this.one(upsertProcessedRqData, arrValues);
            }
            // returning or resolving with undefined ends the sequence;
            // throwing an error will result in a reject;
        }

        db.tx(function (t) {
            return t.sequence(source);
        ...
```

However, the problem is that inside my "source" function, all of my variables are out of scope.  But, according to what I've seen, I'm not really sure why they are.  While debugging it just says that they are 'unavailable'.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for method sequence](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#sequence)? It explains everything. And do not do such things inside a transaction: `var upsertProcessedData = this.getSql('./sql/upsertProcessedData.sql');`, it is a static data, to be loaded once ;)

Comment: Also see this: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/121

Comment: Why you need such a massive transaction, seems like there is some wrong design decisions here?

Comment: It's an excel sheet with potentially 10,000+ rows that need to be inserted into a postgres db